# ros2 python launcher passing through an integer number to another ros2 python launcher

Tags: ros2, python, ros2-launch

i have a ros2 python launcher file with an integer variable named 'drone_id'...
i want to write another ros2 python launcher which only open my main python launcher multiple times and every time pass through a unique 'drone_id' to it.
I've seen https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/Tutorials/Intermediate/Launch/Using-Substitutions.html but i could not solve my problem with it. this should be really easy but as i'm not really familiar with python, i couldn't figure this out...
i've wrote

```
from launch_ros.substitutions import FindPackageShare

from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import IncludeLaunchDescription
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource
from launch.substitutions import PathJoinSubstitution, TextSubstitution


def generate_launch_description():
    

    return LaunchDescription([
        IncludeLaunchDescription(
            PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([
                PathJoinSubstitution([
                    FindPackageShare('plan_manage'),
                    'launch',
                    'my_script_launch.py'
                ])
            ]),
            launch_arguments={
                "drone_id": '0'
            }.items()
        )
    ])
```

this launches my_script_launch.py(my main python launcher)  but i don't know

> 1-how to get and use "drone_id": '0' in the main launcher

> 2-how can i also add launching my_script_launch.py with different "drone_id"s like for example "drone_id": '1'